# ScriptUi - Buttons not responsive with a palette

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

After many attempts I managed to create a working custom progress bar, even if customizing it with the OnDraw command, it flickers (I still don't understand why, maybe it could be the continuous redraw with the update command).
I wanted to add a button that would stop the progress bar (then also the script), and maybe add a warning message, however I ran into a problem.
It seems that the buttons don't respond to clicks, either while the progress bar is advancing or on a normal palette.
On a dialog it works, on palette and window it doesn't.
I suspect it's because, to keep a palette open in photoshop, it has to be busy, otherwise it closes. This causes me to be unable to press the button.
I tried everything I could think of, but nothing worked.
There is a way to implement this?
Here is a sample of my code:

```
    progressbar (100);
    for ( var e = 0; e < 100; e++ ) {
        progressbar.progress ();
        }
    progressbar.close ();

    function progressbar (total) {
        var win = new Window ("palette", undefined, undefined, {closeButton: false, borderless: true});
        win.orientation = "row";
        var barheight = 15;
        var halfbarheight = barheight / 2;
        var barwidth = 500;
        var bar = win.add ("progressbar", [0, 0, barwidth, barheight], 0, total);
        bar.onDraw = function () {
            with (bar) {
                graphics.drawOSControl ();
                graphics.newPath ();
                graphics.moveTo (halfbarheight, 0);
                for (var a = 0; a < Math.PI; a += Math.PI / 100) {
                    graphics.lineTo ((-halfbarheight * Math.sin (a)) + halfbarheight, (-halfbarheight * Math.cos (a)) + halfbarheight);
                    }
                graphics.lineTo (halfbarheight + (bar.value * ((barwidth - barheight) / total)), barheight);
                for (var b = 0; b < Math.PI; b += Math.PI / 100) {
                    graphics.lineTo ((halfbarheight * Math.sin (b)) + halfbarheight + (bar.value * ((barwidth - barheight) / total)), (halfbarheight * Math.cos (b)) + halfbarheight);
                    }
                graphics.lineTo (halfbarheight, 0);
                graphics.closePath ();
                graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.25, 0.83, 0.1]));
                }
            }
        var close = win.add ("iconbutton", [0, 0, 15, 15]);
        close.onDraw = function (event) {
            with (close) {
                graphics.drawOSControl ();
                graphics.ellipsePath (0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
                graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.6, 0, 0]));
                if (event.mouseOver) {
                    graphics.fillPath (graphics.newBrush (graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.85, 0, 0]));
                    }
                }
            }
        close.onClick = function () {
            progressbar.close ();
            return;
            }
        progressbar.close = function () {
            win.close ();
            }
        progressbar.progress = function () {
            bar.value++;
            $.sleep (100);
            win.update ();
            }
        win.show ();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. So, just in case, here is how I used to build a progressbar (with a text area and the button 'Cancel'):

```
var iterations = 10;

// show the progress bar
var bar = new Window('palette', 'Progress...');
var stat = bar.add('statictext', undefined, '');
stat.characters = 80;
var progressbar = bar.add('progressbar', [15,15,600,35], 0, iterations);

var bar_visible = true;
var button = bar.add('button', undefined, 'Cancel');
button.onClick = function() { bar.close(); bar_visible = false; }

bar.center();
bar.show();

var counter = 0;
for (var i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
    if (bar_visible == false) break;

    // update the progress bar
    counter++;
    progressbar.value = counter;
    stat.text = 'Processed ' + counter + ' from ' + iterations;
    bar.update();

    alert(counter); // <------- do stuff
}

// close the progress bar
bar.close();
```

[image]

Note: this example works fine on Windows, but on macOS the alert window blocks the button 'Cancel'. I used the alert window just to show the concept. Otherwise the 'Cancel' button works fine on macOS: it closes the palette and breaks the loop.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have a custom looking progressbar (which I managed to do). The only problem is that the cancel button doesn't work in Photoshop for windows (probably because in PS the palette windows works only when the script is running/busy), and on mac the result is weird.

Comment: The cancel button does not work for me (Mac OS Ventura & ID v18.2.1).  I tried changing the alert() to $.sleep(2000); but that did not help.  The palette window is not selectable and the cursor is a beachball.